Batteries in series have lower voltage than when connected individually
I have two lithium batteries which I test with a purely resistive 755 Ω load:

battery A: CR2032, nominal voltage 3 V; actual voltage 2.97 V without load, 2.24 V with load
battery B: CR2025, nominal voltage 3 V; actual voltage 3.25 V without load, 0.72 V with load

When connected in series, their voltage is 6.22 V without load (as expected), but with load, it's just 1.32 V. Why?

This reads like a quiz question... We are not doing your homework, are we?

Have you looked into battery equivalent models?

You tagged internal-resistance: Did you try and model each battery as a voltage source with series resistance? Result?

What have you done? We don't do homework...

Doesn’t sound like homework at all to me. Ignore the over-confident elitist comments. It’s a good question.

@SteKulov Right, on StackExchange there are no stupid questions, only questions which "sound like homework" :)

As I suspected, but was admittedly too lazy to work it out myself, this phenomenon is explained by the internal resistance of the batteries. If we model each battery as a voltage source with series resistance, we can calculate the internal resistance of each battery from the observed voltages.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
$$
R_a
= \frac{U_a}{I_a}
= \frac{U_a - U_{Rt}^a}{\frac{U_{Rt}^a}{Rt}} 
= \frac{2.97 V - 2.24 V}{\frac{2.24 V}{755 \Omega}}
\doteq 246.05 \Omega
$$
$$
R_b
= \frac{U_b}{I_b}
= \frac{U_b - U_{Rt}^b}{\frac{U_{Rt}^b}{Rt}} 
= \frac{3.25 V - 0.72 V}{\frac{0.72 V}{755 \Omega}}
\doteq 2652.99 \Omega
$$
When we connect the ideal voltage sources in series, producing a total voltage of 6.22V, and load them with their respective internal resistances and the test load Rt, we have a total load of
$$
R
= R_a + R_b + R_t
\doteq 246.05 \Omega + 2652.99 \Omega + 755 \Omega
= 3654.04 \Omega
$$
The current is thus
$$
I
= \frac{U}{R}
\doteq \frac{6.22 V}{3654.04 \Omega}
= 1702.22 \mu A
$$
And the voltage over the test load Rt is
$$
U_{Rt}^{ab}
= I \cdot R
\doteq 1702.22 \mu A \cdot 755 \Omega
= 1.285 V
$$
which is approximately equal to the measured 1.32V.

With the batteries in series and connected to the same load (you didn't say it was a different value to 775 Ω) twice as much current will try and flow and that means the internal ESR may easily come into play and give an exaggerated result.
If full load is 775 Ω for one battery then full load for two batteries in series is 2× 775 Ω.
